# How to use variables inside nested child in ng-repeat?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have the following structure for my views

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in $ctrl.data">
    <div>
        <tr>
            I want to use row value here
        </tr>
        <div>
            I want to use index here
        </div>
    </div>
</tr>
```

I try to use `ng-init` for values or make assign variable like this `{{currentRow = row; currentIndex = index;"'}}"` and use the new values but not working

Can anyone have other idea to solve this problem

Comment: you should be describing your goal, what is it that you want to do? If you want to select some row after clicking it (I assumed because you use `currentRow`), then you need to have `ng-click` on it, where you can set it in a method call

Comment: @AlekseySolovey i want to show some views below to the row by click on the row it self, when the use click button in the row itself the hidden view will be shown

Comment: the button should have `ng-click="currentIndex = $index"` and the hidden views should then have something like `ng-show="currentIndex == $index"`

Answer (score 0):

Please check the example:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('QuestionCtlr', ['$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log) {
    $scope.questions = [
        ["what is 1+1?"],
        ["what color of the sky"],
        ["what is the answer to the universe"]
    ];
    $scope.answers = [
        2, ["blue, black or orange"],
        40
    ];
    $scope.active = null;
    $scope.hideme = function(i) {
        $scope.active = i; 
    }
}]);
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Question</th>
                <th>Answer</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="q in questions">
                <td>{{q[0]}}</td>
                <td ng-class="{hide : active != $index}">{{answers[$index]}}</td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" ng-click="hideme($index)" class="btn btn-default">show me</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/17065/)